# Is it possible that valgrind reports fatal errors of my program which runs correctly?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, valgrind

When I run my program or when I run it with gdb it seems to run correctly, there are no errors and I get an output as expected.

But when I run it with valgrind via `valgrind ./program`, it does not even get far. I get an `VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV)` - exiting
at the very beginning. The valgrind output does not help me at all. I invoke a childprocess, but valgrind does not follow it. I tried to use the `--trace-children=yes` option, but no change.

Another question: What is the difference between the calls `valgrind program` and `valgrind ./program`?

The output I get is:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --trace-children=yes ./program

==2616== Memcheck, a memory error detector

==2616== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.

==2616== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info

==2616== Command: ./program

==2616== 

Parent pid is 2616

Child pid is 2619

main() could not create fifo

--2619-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting

--2619-- si_code=2;  Faulting address: 0x400DFD;  sp: 0x403277b70

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:

   Killed by fatal signal

==2619==    at 0x3802D33A: mash_colon_env (m_libcproc.c:195)

==2619==    by 0x3802D6FD: vgPlain_env_remove_valgrind_env_stuff (m_libcproc.c:254)

==2619==    by 0x3806EB7C: vgSysWrap_generic_sys_execve_before (syswrap-generic.c:2622)

==2619==    by 0x38068750: vgPlain_client_syscall (syswrap-main.c:1443)

==2619==    by 0x380651E9: handle_syscall (scheduler.c:895)

==2619==    by 0x38066D6A: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1091)

==2619==    by 0x380763FC: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:94)

sched status:

  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable

==2619==    at 0x567D957: execve (execve.c:60)

==2619==    by 0x567E1E8: execvpe (execvpe.c:151)

==2619==    by 0x400B2D: main (program2.cpp:34)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I noticed that the 'impossible' tends to happen from time to time with valgrind :( But it's probably your code.

Comment: Are you able to use valgrind on other (test) programs? Have you tried strace to find out where valgrind fails (the "main() could not create fifo" looks suspicious to me) ?

Answer (score 4):

That error indicates that you have most likely encountered a bug in valgrind. In fact it has already been reported (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=271582) so you should add yourself to that bug to be kept up to date with work on fixing it.

In general such "VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR" messages should be reported at https://bugs.kde.org/enter_valgrind_bug.cgi, making sure you you include the full output from running `valgrind -v` on your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Valgrind "follow-fork-mode" child.
That is why Valgrind might not be following your child process.